# pySpark replacing nulls in specific columns

Tags: python, loops, dataframe, pyspark, null

My code below works however it is replacing all nulls in the dataframe to "nI". I only want to replace nulls for the columns that are being renamed. I want to do this without hardcoding any column names.

```
  df =datasetMatchedDomains

  for i in TRUE_matchedAttributeName_List.keys():
      df = df.withColumnRenamed(i,TRUE_matchedAttributeName_List[i]);

  df_final=df.na.fill('NI')
  display(df_final)
else:
  print("clean")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can mention the subset of columns you want in df.na. You can find more info about [here](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.DataFrame.fillna)

Here is an example

```
 df = sc.parallelize([
("portfolio1",None ,"star1"), (None, "Lease", "star2"), ("portfolio2",None, "star3")]).toDF(["a", "b", "c"])

 df.show()

 +----------+-----+-----+
 |         a|    b|    c|
 +----------+-----+-----+
 |portfolio1| null|star1|
 |      null|Lease|star2|
 |portfolio2| null|star3|
 +----------+-----+-----+

TRUE_matchedAttributeName = {'a':'a1'}

subset=[]
for i in TRUE_matchedAttributeName.keys():
   subset.append(TRUE_matchedAttributeName[i])
   df = df.withColumnRenamed(i, TRUE_matchedAttributeName[i])

df.fillna('source not implemented', subset=subset).show(truncate=False)

+----------------------+-----+-----+
|a1                    |b    |c    |
+----------------------+-----+-----+
|portfolio1            |null |star1|
|source not implemented|Lease|star2|
|portfolio2            |null |star3|
+----------------------+-----+-----+
```

Comment: I cannot hard code any column names so this suggestion won't work for me. I was thinking of using TRUE_matchedAttributeName_List[i], but struggling to do it in a list comprehension or for each [i] column ,replace nulls with "string" @rupesh reddy

Comment: @jgtrz, I updated the code according to your requirements. can you check now.

Comment: I have a minor edit to my question. Will add ad "add-on" @rupesh reddy

Comment: @jgtrz,  you mentioned in your question  that` I only want to replace nulls for the columns that are being renamed`. You can add the columns and its rename  in the  dictionary `TRUE_matchedAttributeName`, accordingly, you will see nulls are being replaced by 'source not implemented'

Comment: yes. Your revised code worked. I added another point to my question in post.